# Python PANDAS: Reverse One-Hot Encoding with Duplicate Categories

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with the following general layout:

```
id,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,thing_1,thing_2
1,0,1,1,a,c
2,0,1,1,b,b
3,1,1,0,c,a
```

I would like to accomplish 2 things now:

-Create duplicate records where there can only be one true(1) indicator per row

-Create an additional column where the value is the true(1) indicator name

```
id,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,thing_1,thing_2,ind_any
1,0,1,0,a,c,ind_2
1,0,0,1,a,c,ind_3
2,0,1,0,b,b,ind_2
2,0,0,1,b,b,ind_3
3,1,0,0,c,a,ind_1
3,0,1,0,c,a,ind_2
```

Any tips welcome!

Comment: The splitting of the vector [0, 1, 1] can be done by taking the dot product with each of the unit vectors in turn: [0, 1, 1]•[1, 0, 0] = [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]•[0, 1, 0] = [0, 1, 0], etc. You'd have to discard the all 0 results, which might hurt any efficiency gains though. This could also be viewed as a bitfield/bitmasking operation.

Comment: @Scott Colby Thanks for the tips!  In my real use case, there are actually quite a number of indicator columns, so I have been trying to avoid taking the dot products if I can possible avoid it.  I'll take a look at bitmasking approaches and start iterating.  Who knows?  Someone else might weigh in in the meantime.